# Which of the following is true (Gate)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two linearly independent solutions of $y'' + \sin(x)y$ , $0 \leq x \leq 1$ .Let $g(x) = W(y_1, y_2)$ be  the Wronskian of $y_1\ \ and \ \ y_2$. Then

1. $\frac{dg}{dx} > 0\ \ on\ \ [0,1]$
2. $\frac{dg}{dx} < 0\ \ on\ \ [0,1]$
3. $\frac{dg}{dx}$  vanishes at only one point of $[0,1]$
4. $\frac{dg}{dx}$  vanishes at all point of $[0,1]$

I think 3.) and 4.) is false because Wronskian is non zero for all x in $[0,1]$

Please  tell me abut 1.) and 4.)

Answer (score 0):

Only 4. is right, as
$$
g(x)=\left|
\begin{matrix}
y_1&y_2\\y'_1&y_2'
\end{matrix}
\right|,
$$
and
$$
g'(x)=\left|
\begin{matrix}
y_1'&y_2'\\y'_1&y_2'
\end{matrix}
\right|+\left|
\begin{matrix}
y_1&y_2\\y''_1&y_2''
\end{matrix}
\right|=0+\left|
\begin{matrix}
y_1&y_2\\-\sin x\, y_1&-\sin x\,y_2=
\end{matrix}
\right|=-(\sin x)\, \left|
\begin{matrix}
y_1&y_2\\y_1&y_2
\end{matrix}
\right|=0.
$$